# Write GPIO Raspberry PI 2 B+

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, gpio, raspberry-pi2

I am new to Raspberry Pi. I need to read and write to the GPIO pins on the Raspberry Pi. I am trying to do this operation in php, python, and the command line. Do I need to download any kind of library to do this in php, python, or command line?

Comment: See also http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/27607/19949

Answer (score 3):

No, controlling GPIOs from userspace is a feature provided by the operating system. You just need to write a number to the GPIO value "file" thats provided by the kernel. It is located under `/sys/class/gpio/gpio<number>/value`. This should give you a [kickstart](http://beaglebone.cameon.net/home/using-the-gpios). There they show how its done on the BeagleBoard with the shell but it is a general concept and it doesnt matter which language you use.

Answer (score 3):

In python you can use the [GPIO library](http://makezine.com/projects/tutorial-raspberry-pi-gpio-pins-and-python/)

Generally in unix devices are represented as files, so you can open a file in /dev/ and read/write to the devices.

You might get more detailed help on https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

Besides `sysfs`, the virtual filesystem that allows `root` to directly read from and write to GPIO pins by `echo` to or `cat` from various files in the `/sys/class/gpio/` folder (as already mentioned) there are libraries available to do so. Two noteworthy examples are:

1. `wiringPi` library provides a cli command `gpio` to be used by non-privileged users for direct access.
2. `pigs` utility, part of the `pigpio` library also offers comprehensive control of the GPIO pins from the command line (see [pigpio](http://abyz.co.uk/rpi/pigpio/pigs.html) for download of source, installation procedures and excellent application examples).